# How to refresh my viewpager with fragment on its onsetpagelistner?

Tags: android

In my fragment i have listviews.When i swipe to different tabs and again back to same listview tab  then the values increase.It is not refreshing the old values in list.Can anyone suggest any option to solve this

I done with this http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Have you tried notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: yes.But did'nt worked

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        adapter.addFrag(new Area(), "Area");
        adapter.addFrag(new AreaList(), "Area List");     
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

Comment: plz chk out my edit

Comment: Any one have any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime clear your list, then it will be work

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) 
{ adapter.addFrag(new Area(), "Area");
 adapter.addFrag(new AreaList(), "Area List");
 viewPager.setAdapter(adapter); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

Comment: What to do for that?Did'nt get you

Comment: Can we refresh viewpger with its position in onPageChangeListner

Comment: Ok ,done.I gave list.clear(); in fragment.It works.But can we refresh with pagechangelistner ,then can reduce wrk time.

Comment: list.clear() method used to clear the list , it is not time consuming process. If you rae satisfied then please up vote my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh your listview by using `setUserVisibleHint` method

```
        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
            if (isVisibleToUser) {
                //Do your work, fragment now visible 
                //Fetch your dataset again or just refresh dataset
          }
        }
```